# Mapstruct a List inside an object to a List

Tags: java, maps, mapstruct

My target is a List and the Source is a List that is inside an Object, check the source:

```
public class ResponseTransactionChm8t003_1 {

    @Campo(indice = 1, nombre = "listMarginReportDTOOut", tipo = TipoCampo.LIST)
    private List<Listmarginreportdtoout> listMarginReportDTOOut;
    
}
```

How can I map this? I tried,

```
    @Mapping(target="List<BDtoOutCreateGenerateMarginReportPost>",source="listMarginReportDTOOut", qualifiedByName="mapListResponse")
    List<BDtoOutCreateGenerateMarginReportPost> mapToRespose(ResponseTransactionChm8t003_1 responseTransactionChm8t003_1);

    @Named("mapListResponse")
    default List<Listmarginreportdtoout> ResponseTransactionChm8t003_1ToList(ResponseTransactionChm8t003_1 responseTransactionChm8t003_1){
        return responseTransactionChm8t003_1.getListMarginReportDTOOut();
    }
```

But it doesn't work, I throws  **Can't generate mapping method from non-iterable type to iterable type.**

Answer (score 0):

You can write out the conversion from `Object` to `List` manually and have mapstruct do the `List<A>` to `List<B>` conversion.

For example like this:

```
    default List<BDtoOutCreateGenerateMarginReportPost> mapToResponse(ResponseTransactionChm8t003_1 responseTransactionChm8t003_1){
        return mapToListResponse(responseTransactionChm8t003_1.getListMarginReportDTOOut());
    }

    List<BDtoOutCreateGenerateMarginReportPost> mapToListResponse(List<Listmarginreportdtoout> list);
```